# const in shared_ptr: do I need two or only one

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I run into this piece of code:

```
const std::shared_ptr<const T>& a_shared_pointer,
```

I am really curious what do the two **const** mean? Do they mean the same thing? *a_shared_pointer* is a shared pointer that points to something we can't modify?

Comment: ***Do they mean the same thing?*** No, the shared pointer itself and the object pointed to are both constant.

Comment: `a_shared_pointer` is a reference, not a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

A shared pointer is analgous to a raw pointer in terms of dereferencing and constness.

#### Example:

Note that below, the term `[const]` means we can choose whether to insert const or not:

`[const] X * [const] p;`

#### Gives us 4 options with regards to constness:

`X* p;` - p is a mutable pointer (it can be changed to point at a different X) to a mutable X

`const X *p` - p is a mutable pointer to an immutable X

`X * const p;` - p is an immutable pointer (can only point to this X) to a mutable X

`const X * const p;` - p is an immutable pointer (can only point to this X) to an immutable X

#### Similarly with shared_ptr:

`std::shared_ptr<T> &p` - reference to a mutable pointer to a mutable T

`const std::shared_ptr<T> &p` - reference to an immutable pointer to a mutable T

`std::shared_ptr<const T> &p` - reference to a mutable pointer to an immutable T

`const std::shared_ptr<const T> &p` - reference to an immutable pointer to an immutable T

Answer (score 1):

a_shared pointer is a reference to a `const std::shared_ptr` (e.g. you can't call not const operations on the pointer through this reference, like `reset` etc.), pointing at a `const T` meaning that the pointed to object is also const (so again, you can't do `a_shared_ptr->non_const_method()`).